# In Shiny, object of type 'closure' is not subsettable despite using parantheses

Tags: r, shiny

In Shiny, I want to create a reactive object, a dataframe, that updates a plot automatically when values in that object change. I am aware that one needs to use parentheses for that object in subsequent usage. For some reason, I am still getting the error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable".

I have tried to reactive(), reactiveValues() and reactiveVal(), but none produce the desired result. Any ideas?

```
require(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

# data pre-processing
# loading data from local machine
data(mtcars)

df <- mtcars
# processe
min.y <- min(df$mpg)
max.y <- max(df$mpg)
mean.y <- mean(df$mpg)



ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "y.value",
                  label = "Filter mpg",
                  min = min.y, 
                  max = max.y, 
                  value = c(mean.y-1, mean.y+1),
                  step = 0.5)

      ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    ))))


server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- reactive({

    relevant.values <- input$y.value

    df <- df[which(df$mpg %in% relevant.values[1]:relevant.values[2]),]

    df

  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    mydata <- df()


    # relevant.values <- input$y.value
    # data <- df[which(df$mpg %in% relevant.values[1]:relevant.values[2]),]

    ggplot(mydata, aes(x = hp , y = mpg )) + geom_line()


  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are two problems with your code:

1. You can't create a reactive expression called `df` which modifies an object called `df`, i.e. the same as the expression;
2. The code `which(df$mpg %in% relevant.values[1]:relevant.values[2])` does not filter the values of mpg between `relevant.values[1]` and `relevant.values[2]` but it selects the values of mpg which are exactly equal to `relevant.values[1]:relevant.values[2]`.

I modified your script as follows:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

# data pre-processing
# loading data from local machine
data(mtcars)

df <- mtcars
# processe
min.y <- min(df$mpg)
max.y <- max(df$mpg)
mean.y <- mean(df$mpg)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(
        inputId = "y.value",
        label = "Filter mpg",
        min = min.y,
        max = max.y,
        value = c(mean.y - 1, mean.y + 1),
        step = 0.5
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
))


server <- function(input, output) {
  filtered_df <- reactive({
    df[which(df$mpg >= input$y.value[1] & df$mpg <= input$y.value[2]), ]
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered_df(), aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_line()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for all the useful suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The error is primarily because you have an object called `df` which is a copy of `mtcars` as well as a reactive object called `df`.

Renaming your reactive is the easier fix:

```
require(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

# data pre-processing
# loading data from local machine
data(mtcars)

df <- mtcars
# processe
min.y <- min(df$mpg)
max.y <- max(df$mpg)
mean.y <- mean(df$mpg)



ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "y.value",
                  label = "Filter mpg",
                  min = min.y, 
                  max = max.y, 
                  value = c(mean.y-1, mean.y+1),
                  step = 0.5)

    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    ))))


server <- function(input, output) {

  dfr <- reactive({

    relevant.values <- input$y.value

    df <- df[which(df$mpg %in% relevant.values[1]:relevant.values[2]),]

    df

  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    mydata <- dfr()


    # relevant.values <- input$y.value
    # data <- df[which(df$mpg %in% relevant.values[1]:relevant.values[2]),]

    ggplot(mydata, aes(x = hp , y = mpg )) + geom_line()


  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This was precisely the problem! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this, please try it and tell me if is ok.

```
require(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

data(mtcars)

df <- mtcars

min.y <- min(df$mpg)
max.y <- max(df$mpg)
mean.y <- mean(df$mpg)



ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(

 sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput(inputId = "y.value",
              label = "Filter mpg",
              min = min.y, 
              max = max.y, 
              value = c(mean.y-1, mean.y+1),
              step = 0.5)

 ),
 mainPanel(
  plotOutput("plot")
 ))))


 server <- function(input, output) {

 output$plot<- renderPlot({




  output$plot <- renderPlot({


a=input$y.value[1] ; b=input$y.value[2]

hp_reac <- df$hp[a:b]

mpg_reac <- df$mpg[a:b]

ggplot(df[a:b,], aes(x = hp_reac , y = mpg_reac )) + geom_line()

})


})


 }

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works too, but I want to use reactive for another purpose.